# ASPxUploadControl: how to synchronize data from two controls?

Tags: devexpress

I need to have TWO ASPxUploadControl controls on the same Web page. A single UPLOAD button should start the uploading from the both controls. This is simple: in Jscript code I call Upload() method for the both controls; on the server side I handle FilesUploadComplete event on the both controls.

But I have the following problem – my application needs to have  UploadedFiles  lists from the both controls SIMULTANEOUSLY. When FilesUploadComplete event handler is called for the 1st ASPxUploadControl, property UploadedFiles of the 2nd control is null. And, correspondingly, when FilesUploadComplete event handler is called for the 2nd ASPxUploadControl, property UploadedFiles of the 1st control is null.

Can I resolve the trouble somehow? I could upload the files using Postback – do perform postback of the whole form when the UPLOAD button is clicked. This gives me the both UploadedFiles  lists simultaneously, but leads to another problem:  Progress Indicator does not work in Postback mode. This is not acceptable for me – I want uploadcing progress to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange situation but you could try this:
1. Send both upload controls file list to server before you call Upload methods trigger. You can do this by calling custom http handler using ajax. If you use jQuery:

```js
$.ajax(
{
    url: 'MyHandler.ashx',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: { fileList1: uploadControlFileList1, fileList2: uploadControlFileList2},
    success: function ()
    {
        // call Upload methods here;
    }
});
```

2.In your handler save those file lists in your db together with session id. Or you could store this list in session if it is easier for you. Also store time when file list is received.

3.When you receive file(s) check if you have it in your list and try to pair it with other control files. If necessary Use time from step 2 to choose between filelists. Mark file as uploaded when you receive it. Wait for other control files. When all controls files are uploaded remove fileLists from session/db and continue with your logic.

There is some work with this but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single ASPxUploadControl instance with multiple file inputs. See the “Upload Control - Multi-File Upload” http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/UploadControl/MultiFileUpload.aspx online demo regarding this.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. My application needs TWO ASPxUploadControl controls (each one with SEVEAL file input fields). I need something like two file ‘panels’; left one will be the 1st ASPxUploadControl instance and the right one will be the 2nd ASPxUploadControl instance. After UPLOAD is clicked, I have to upload all the files from the both controls and make pairs <File from the left panel with index [i], File from the right panel with index [i]>.